# Solution of matrix equations

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, X= \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 7 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$

\begin{align}
AX=B A^{-1} & \text{(from right side)} \\
A^{-1} AX = A^{-1}B \\
EX = A^{-1}B \\
X = A^{-1}B 
\end{align}

So, now I have to find the inverse matrix.

$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)}* (\text{adj} A)^T$$

$$\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix} 3 & -2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}=4$$
$$\text{adj}(A)=\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\ A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33} \end{bmatrix}$$

So, now that I found all the elements for the adjA, I get the following matrix:
$$\text{adj}(A)=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -4 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$(\text{adj}A)^T=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 2 & -4 \\ 3 & -1 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$$

So, the inverse matrix is equal to:
$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 2 & -4 \\ 3 & -1 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$$

When I do the math, I get the following matrix:
$$A^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\ -\frac{2}{4} & \frac{2}{4} & -\frac{4}{4} \\ \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{8}{4} \end{bmatrix}$$

Now the final equation $X = A^{-1} B$ is:
$$A^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\ -\frac{2}{4} & \frac{2}{4} & -\frac{4}{4} \\ \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{8}{4} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 7 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} = \, ?$$

The solution is supposed to be 
$$X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 7 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

But I can't get that solution when I multiply my equations what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first entry in adj$A$ should be 1

Comment: Thanks, my bad while writing online, but I did get 1 on my notebook. But it still doesn't help get the right solution for X.

Comment: B is $(1,7,2)^T$, $X$ should be something else.  What do you get for your final matrix product (with 1/4 instead of -1/4)?

Comment: So the problem is not my way of solving the equation, but the solution is wrong in the notebook?